# Unity iOS build app size is too big (1.7 GB), 30x larger than Android?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a simple 2D game in Unity. 
Android build results into 55Mb APK file, while iOS build (after Archiving) takes the enormously huge size of 1.7GB.

From Build Report:

```
Uncompressed usage by category:
Textures      1541.8 mb  71.3%
```

So the most part of that size is textures.
What are possible solutions to fix the textures size for iOS build?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my case the solution was to change the compression method for the iOS build in Unity editor:

```
Build Settings -> Compression Method -> LZ4HC
```

It helped me to reduce the archived app size from 1.7 GB to just 84MB.

Comment: Changing the compression method indeed solves the problem. Mine dropped from 800 MB to 150 MB.